# Button to mute/unmute video bg on divi theme

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a website for a client using the divi theme. The site has a background video with sound. The customer wants in the video a button to turn the sound on and off.

With the following code I was able to mute but I can not make a button to turn on and off.

Can someone help me?

```
jQuery (document) .ready (function () {
  jQuery (". et_pb_section_video_bg video"). prop ('muted', true);
});
```

Comment: There is too many spaces every where here.

Answer (score 0):

Try with volume level!

**Edit**
And here are the functions for some volume down/up buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Video element
  var myVideo = $(".et_pb_section_video_bg video")[0];

  // On load state (muted)
  myVideo.volume = 0;

  $("#sound_up").on("click",function(){
    var actual_volume = myVideo.volume;
    if(actual_volume<1){
      myVideo.volume += 0.2;
    }
  });

  $("#sound_down").on("click",function(){
    var actual_volume = myVideo.volume;
    if(actual_volume>0){
      myVideo.volume -= 0.2;
    }
  });
});
```

Assuming the `et_pb_section_video_bg video` class is on the video element...

Comment: The code I quoted worked to mute the video but I need the video to be muted and have a button to turn the sound on and off.

Can you help me?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: unfortunately it did not work with the sound volume, any other way?

Thank you!

Comment: Not another way... Make this way work. Do you use the right selector? Is `.et_pb_section_video_bg video` the right class for your video element? Is there more than one? Do you have jQuery loaded? Is there errors in the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337) ?